# JavaScript/JQUERY improve code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got Js/Jquery code to trigger show/hide on hover of the colored "X". Each "X" has a different div and content to display. I know there is a better way to code the Js/Jquery other that repeating the same code but just changing the name of the div each "X" is calling for. You can see this in action in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rolando_pdl/uF5pw/2/)
I'm also using the Jquery **qtips** plugin to get the fading boxes to work
I will appreciate any advice on how to code this better.
 Thanks 
Below is an example of the Js/Jquery that I'm talking about

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.trigger').mouseover(function (event) {
        $('.box').fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $('.trigger').mouseout(function (event) {
        $('.box').fadeOut(1000);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box2').hide();
    $('.trigger2').mouseover(function (event) {
        $('.box2').fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $('.trigger2').mouseout(function (event) {
        $('.box2').fadeOut(1000);
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.box3').hide();
        $('.trigger3').mouseover(function (event) {
            $('.box3').fadeIn(1000);
        });
        $('.trigger3').mouseout(function (event) {
            $('.box3').fadeOut(1000);
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.box4').hide();
            $('.trigger4').mouseover(function (event) {
                $('.box4').fadeIn(1000);
            });
            $('.trigger4').mouseout(function (event) {
                $('.box4').fadeOut(1000);
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.box5').hide();
                $('.trigger5').mouseover(function (event) {
                    $('.box5').fadeIn(1000);
                });
                $('.trigger5').mouseout(function (event) {
                    $('.box5').fadeOut(1000);
                });

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.box6').hide();
                    $('.trigger6').mouseover(function (event) {
                        $('.box6').fadeIn(1000);
                    });
                    $('.trigger6').mouseout(function (event) {
                        $('.box6').fadeOut(1000);
                    });
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.box7').hide();
                        $('.trigger7').mouseover(function (event) {
                            $('.box7').fadeIn(1000);
                        });
                        $('.trigger7').mouseout(function (event) {
                            $('.box7').fadeOut(1000);
                        });
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('.box8').hide();
                            $('.trigger8').mouseover(function (event) {
                                $('.box8').fadeIn(1000);
                            });
                            $('.trigger8').mouseout(function (event) {
                                $('.box8').fadeOut(1000);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure stackoverflow is a place for "Please refactor my code which works but isn't very modular"!!

Comment: This might get closed as Off Topic/belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: true that... but seeing as how he's only earned 11 points so far, that means he's probably only not answered like 1 question.

Answer (score 3):

First, You should try using the jquery .hover() method, because it is usually more reliable in terms of registering a mouse out and not firing multiple events.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Secondly,

you only need to wrap your code in one document ready function, not several. it would have the same result

Comment: Thanks, I realized that, I'm trying to get better with this stuff that's why I'm posting questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you change your div classes to all be `.box` and `.trigger` (instead of box2, box3, trigger2, trigger3, etc), you should only need this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.trigger').mouseover(function(event){
        $(this).closest('.box').fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $('.trigger').mouseout(function(event){
        $(this).closest('.box').fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/closest/

You haven't shown your html, so I'm guessing here. You may be able to use `$(this).parents('.box')` or `$(this).find('.box')` instead.

Comment: Thanks jrummell, there is a link to the code where it says "You can see this in action in this fiddle"

Answer (score 1):

How about a function and for loop?

```
function BindTrigger(index){
    index = (index == 0 ? '' : index);
    $('.trigger'+ index).hover(function(){
        $('.box'+ index).fadeIn(1000);
    }, function(){
        $('.box'+ index).fadeOut(1000);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        BindTrigger(i);
});
```

**Edit: jrummell's method will be more efficient and reliable.**